# Either SCP roles claim need to be present in the token

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

In our application, we are trying to connect the share point using Microsoft Graph. We configured Delegate permission in Azure AD.

1. We got the code for the individual user.
2. Passed the code as a parameter to generate the Access Token- Token generated.
3. When we tried hitting the graph URL using the generated access token we are getting below error.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "Access Denied",
    "message": "Either SCP roles claim need to be present in the token.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "32e7d9cc-a974-4ba4-92b2-14831bb84d87",
      "date": "2020-03-31T09:01:49"
    }
  }
}
```

Client ID and Tenant ID are being passed correctly.

We followed this documentation: [Delegated permission - Send email with Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/questions/10047/delegated-permission-send-email-with-microsoft-gra.html).

Comment: Which API did you want to call?

Comment: How are you passing the token to the API? Have you confirmed the token includes the scopes ( `scp`) you've requested? Which scopes have you requested?

Comment: We are using graph API, Scopes are passed as openid Sites.FullControl.All. Apart from that we have requested 4 scopes APPS ON AZURE GRAPH API permission Permission Type
Directory.AccessAsUser.All 
Files.Read.All 
Sites.Read.All 
User.Read

Comment: I followed a 2 step approach like, First request to find out the code.  https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantID}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=1{clientid}&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost&scope=openid Sites.FullControl.All&state=12345&response_mode=query

Comment: Step 2: To find out the access token by passing the code as parameter.   https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/token passed in header clientID,Grant type as authorization code,Client secret,resource,scope as Sites.fullcontrol.all, Code.  we followed the similar to my original post link

Comment: Have you inspected the token at e.g. jwt.io to see the permissions are in the token? And please provide a screenshot of your Delegate permission in Azure AD.

Answer (score 0):

I followed your steps and it worked fine. I will provide some screenshots for you to have a double check.

1.Register an application and add `Sites.FullControl.ALL` permission of **Microsoft Graph API**

[image]

2.Get the code

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/XX.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=702b90f1-f6b9***-b71f-13edfcaa0c25
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=openid Sites.FullControl.All
&state=12345
```

3.Get access token

[image]

4.Call Microsoft Graph API

[image]